# How to create array in openpyxl and append the cell values in that array just by iterating through row cells

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am having one excel sheet and i have to iterate the row up to certain value( like `cell.value="cxc"`)

If cell is having that particular value it should stop and create an array with all the iterated values in it.

After reaching to that particular value it should iterate again to the maximum column and create an new array of that values

```
mylist = []
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "CXC Type":
            break
            print(cell.coordinate ,end=" ")
        else:
            mylist.append(cell.value)
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Include some code.

Comment: Did you know the Column of `cell.value == "CXC Type"`? You are appending from a **Range** to `mylist`, is this what you want?

Comment: i am having range of worksheet like ws['F2':'AB3'].now the sheet is updated and last column is AR3...so i am able o calculate number of rows and columns in sheet. so how i should give range so that every time list changes it will give us correct output

Comment: I have answered this at your Question: [how to give range of a worksheet as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46298094/7414759). Plase avoid duplicate Questions, delete this or the other.