# how to give range of a worksheet as variable

Tags: python, range, openpyxl

I am having one excel sheet which is used to read the data through python openpyxl...so in my script i have values that are hard coded as ws['E2':'AB3'] as AB3 is the last entry to be read...but now the sheet is updated and now last cell coordinate is AR3...how can i make the code generic so that every time sheet updates the code should work..?
Note(i find out total number of rows and column in sheet...what can i do)

```
rows = ws.max_row
column = ws.max_column
print(rows,column)
column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
print(column_letter)
```

Comment: Please be more specific, do you want it to automatically load specific column types or just be able to load all of the columns?

Comment: load all the columns till last

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: how can i make the code generic
>
> **Note**: I assume you always want to start at 'E2'.

```
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
# Define only start 'E2',     
# all max_* values, last Row, Column, are returned by Default
min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries('E2')

# Iterate all Rows, starting at min_row == 2
for columns in worksheet.iter_rows(min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row, max_col=max_col, max_row=max_row):
    # Iterate all Columns, starting at min_col == 'E'
    for cell in columns:
        print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value) )
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to load all of the columns, use pandas, its simpler and has much more functionality.

```
import pandas as pd

# Load in the Excel file (sheetname is optional, defaults to first sheet)
df = pd.read_excel('/some/file/path/excel_file_name.xlsx', sheetname='Sheetx')

# Check the first 5 rows
print(df.head())
```

Comment: how can i give the range of the worksheet as WS['F2':'A03'] to WS['F2':'AR3']  i convert the column number to column letter so for 44 it is AR so i did this rows = ws.max_row
column = ws.max_column
print(rows,column)
column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
print(column_letter) //print AR
count = column_letter //put AR in count variable
fatrows=ws['F2':'count3']...but it is not working how can i made it possible....please help me

Comment: openpyxl or xlrd (used internally by Pandas) give users more control over how worksheets are read.